# d3 parallel coordinates datetime axis

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js, graph, parallel-coordinates

I am trying to make a parallel coordinates graph and developing based on http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281 example.

What do I need to alter/modify/add in the code if I want to use DateTime format attribute as one of axis in the graph?

Comment: FYI: you can also take a look at this library, I find it very easy to use https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/

Answer (score 1):

I think it would suffice to add the times as the number of milliseconds since epoch to the csv file, the following lines will then convert the string to number:

```
// Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
  return d != "name" && (y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
    .range([height, 0]));
}));
```

`p[d]` when the new column (let's call it `time`) is reached, executing `d3.extent` over the cars for that particular column will get the max and min values (as numbers) and will map them to the range [height, 0], so that whenever you execute `y['time'](value)` and value is in the range `[min, max]` it will be mapped to one value between `[height, 0]`

To get the times elapsed for a new date since epoch run `+(new Date())`, the params to the `Date` constructor will be the ones you decide for this case.

One problem that I found is the labeling (the numbers will be something like `1426573656530`) so I'd use [tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) to change the labels of each axis

Comment: Hi @mauricio-poppe  can you help solve the issues with these parallel coordinates - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329600/d3-v4-parallel-coordinates-selection-of-paths-with-d3-v4-brushes     or    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334965/syntagmatic-nutrient-parallel-coordinate-chart-highlight-data-row  . It would be of great help. Thanks in advance.